# Adding singleton method and accessing instance variables - Undefined

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Okay so I was attempting to [solve step 2 in this puzzle](http://ruby-metaprogramming.rubylearning.com/) and I am having trouble. My problem is upon trying to access an instance variable `(@name)` or even call methods on the class `(name getter)`, ruby tells me undefined local variable. To me this seems like a scope problem. The problem comes up when an action name and a block is given as a parameter. A singleton is being successfully added to the instance variable I believe but calling it, ruby tells me that "name" is an undefined local variable. Any ideas? Any idea how the functionality could be emulated some other way more efficiently?

Here is my **Dog.rb** class:

```
class Dog
  MSGS = {:dance => 'is dancing', :poo => 'is a smelly doggy!', :laugh => 'finds this hilarious!'}
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def can(*actions)
    actions.each do |action|
      self.instance_eval do
        if block_given?
          define_singleton_method action do
            yield
          end
        else
          define_singleton_method(action) do
            name + ' ' + MSGS[action]
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def method_missing(method_name,*args)
    name + " can't " + method_name.to_s
  end
end
```

And here is the Dog_Game.rb from the puzzle:

```
require './dog'

lassie, fido, stimpy = %w[Lassie Fido Stimpy].collect{|name| Dog.new(name)}
lassie.can :dance, :poo, :laugh
fido.can(:poo){"#{name} is just wayyyy too smelly."} #name here is the source of the problem
stimpy.can :dance
stimpy.can(:cry){"#{name} cried AHHHH"}

p lassie.dance
p lassie.poo
p lassie.laugh
puts
p fido.dance
p fido.poo
p fido.laugh
puts
p stimpy.dance
p stimpy.poo
p stimpy.laugh
p stimpy.cry
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1:
  you create a ugly method:

self.instance_eval {} == define_singleton_method(callback, &block)

you should use one but not both!

2:
because the scope is changed when you use

```
self.instance_eval do 
   #coding
end
```

you can't use the varible :name, so just use define_singleton_method!

sorry, my english is very poor!

Answer (score 1):

Pass the block to `define_singleton_method` if it's what you want the method to be:

```ruby
def can(*actions, &block)
  actions.each do |action|
    if block_given?
      define_singleton_method(action, block)
    else
      define_singleton_method(action) { "#{name} #{MSGS[action]}" }
    end
  end
end
```

This outputs what you expect.

<sup>*(Delta putting stimpy first to prove `cry` isn't on the other instances, and a `cry` call on each.)*</sup>

```
Stimpy is dancing
Stimpy can't poo
Stimpy can't laugh
Stimpy cried AHHHH

Lassie is dancing
Lassie is a smelly doggy!
Lassie finds this hilarious!
Lassie can't cry

Fido can't dance
Fido is just wayyyy too smelly.
Fido can't laugh
Fido can't cry
```